# Typewriter render from list of C# class names

Tags: c#, typescript, typewriter

I am looking for a configuration(template file) of generating typescript files from a list of C# classes using Typewriter.
Something like this below:

```
   $Classes(['myclass1','myclass2','myclass3'])[
export class $Name {
    $Properties[
    // $LoudName
    public $name: $Type = $Type[$Default];]
}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a lambda expression to filter the classes e.g.

```
$Classes(c => c.Name == "myclass1" || c.Name == "myclass2" || c.Name == "myclass3")[
export class $Name {
    $Properties[
    // $LoudName
    public $name: $Type = $Type[$Default];]
}]
```